# Write an image to Google Storage throwing API CallNotFoundExcpetion

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk

I'm working on trying to store images in Google Storage and found some test code via one of their forums.

I've added the various dependencies and was looking to step through the code however I've encountered this exception before getting very far at all.  I should add that this is local testing and not using the appEngine and that I have looked for various resources online but came up at a loss.

The code that I found is (I've modified bucket name and url of file):

```java
    public static void test() throws IOException {
        GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
        BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

        GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
                .mimeType(".jpg")
                .acl("project-private")
                .build();

        String bucketName = "my_test_bucket";
        String secureFilename = "https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/_jcr_content/main-pars/image.img.jpg/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_1000x560.jpg";

        GcsFilename p_filename = new GcsFilename(bucketName, secureFilename);
        GcsOutputChannel writeChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(p_filename, options); //exception here
        //writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(image.getImageData()));
        writeChannel.close();

        BlobKey blobKey = blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey("/gs/" + p_filename.getBucketName() + "/" + p_filename.getObjectName());

        ImagesService imageService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
        ServingUrlOptions servoptions = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey).secureUrl(true);
        String url = imageService.getServingUrl(servoptions);
    }
```

The exception occurs when createOrReplace is called.

The exception is:

```
        Apr 12, 2019 4:37:48 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
    WARNING: RetryHelper(432.2 ms, 1 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@12331b): Attempt 1 failed, sleeping for 85 ms: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call file.Create in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
    Apr 12, 2019 4:37:48 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
    WARNING: RetryHelper(621.2 ms, 2 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@12331b): Attempt 2 failed, sleeping for 128 ms: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call file.Create in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
    Apr 12, 2019 4:37:48 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
    WARNING: RetryHelper(761.3 ms, 3 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@12331b): Attempt 3 failed, sleeping for 253 ms: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call file.Create in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
    Apr 12, 2019 4:37:48 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
    WARNING: RetryHelper(1.026 s, 4 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@12331b): Attempt 4 failed, sleeping for 495 ms: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call file.Create in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
    Apr 12, 2019 4:37:49 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
    WARNING: RetryHelper(1.533 s, 5 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@12331b): Attempt 5 failed, sleeping for 1278 ms: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call file.Create in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
    Apr 12, 2019 4:37:50 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
    WARNING: RetryHelper(2.824 s, 6 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@12331b): Attempt 6 failed, sleeping for 2984 ms: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call file.Create in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57754', transport: 'socket'
    com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetriesExhaustedException: RetryHelper(2.832 s, 6 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@12331b): Too many failures, giving up
        at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:100)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:123)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl.createOrReplace(GcsServiceImpl.java:32)
        at gametest.Application.test(Application.java:55)
        at gametest.Application.main(Application.java:69)
    Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call file.Create in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
        at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException.foreignThread(ApiProxy.java:800)
        at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:112)
        at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:65)
        at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:591)
        at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.create(FileServiceImpl.java:512)
        at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.createNewGSFile(FileServiceImpl.java:157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.beginObjectCreation(LocalRawGcsService.java:106)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.beginObjectCreation(LocalRawGcsService.java:44)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1.run(GcsServiceImpl.java:35)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1.run(GcsServiceImpl.java:32)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:78)
        ... 4 more

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

any help to resolve would be awesome, thank you in advance.

Comment: use threadmanager to spawn a thread and run your code in there

Comment: @Dylan, since your comment I've tried to implement it in various ways, all with no success leading to another question posted.  I don't suppose you're able to point me to an example anywhere?  I've search but haven't found anything concrete, the examples that I've found don't seem to work or are very particular to that use case.

Comment: Will you run your code in appengine ? or you should use https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

Comment: @howie, thank you!  I think I was looking in the wrong places for sure :D 

I'm not sure how/where it'll deployed at the moment but seeing as it's not in the AppEngine I know to focus on the alternative :)

Comment: "LocalRawGcsService" is the fake version of GCS that runs in the local App Engine dev server. It's possible that there is some config issue or a bug in the dev server or a problem with how your test is being invoked. It might work fine when actually deployed.

Comment: Could you share more details about your setup? How you add dependencies, which tools you use. In the end, did it work once deployed on App Engine?